# jquery code to extract value from string

Tags: jquery

I have a text

```
"Follow Up=10;Meeting=90;Research=20;Transferred=83;"
```

It's not necessary that the text starts with Follow Up

I want to extract only the value associated to Follow Up which is 10. Can you please provide jQuery code to get that?

Comment: You can use string in JSON format and then parse to get specific value

Comment: or use a simple regex /Follow Up=[0-9]+/gi

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies. Can you provide the code using the Regex?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery to do this, you can use plain Javascript:

```
var string = 'Follow Up=10;Meeting=90;Research=20;Transferred=83;';

//remove trailing semicolon
string = string.replace(/;$/, '');

var values = {};

string.split(';').forEach(function(item) {
  var components = item.split('=');
  values[components[0]] = components[1];
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using `split`:

```
var keyValues = [];
var string = 'Follow Up=10;Meeting=90;Research=20;Transferred=83;';

string.split(';').forEach(function(elemString){
   var elem = elemString.split('=');
   if(elem.length == 2){
      keyValues[elem[0]]=elem[1];
   }
});

console.log(keyValues['Follow Up']); //you can acces any of the other keys as well like keyValues['Meeting'].
```

Edit: mixed with Brendan Nee's answer so no jQuery is needed.

With the `regex`:

```
var Regex =  /Follow Up=([0-9]+)/gi;
var matches = Regex.exec(string);
console.log(matches[1]);
```